# Does setting an item null in a .NET List<T> make it available for Garbage Collection and is it a good idea?

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I have a large list where each item is processed once then never looked at again during a long operation:

```
List<T> items;
 // ... some stuff is done with the list then finally

 for(int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
 {
     SomeOperation(items[i]);
     //items[i] never used again at this point
     // say i do this:
     // items[i] = null;

 }
```

If I uncomment `items[i] = null`, will this unroot the object at index `i` and make it available for Garbage Collection?

Would it be more efficient, from a memory usage standpoint, to do this versus letting GC happen later when the entire list is unused down the road.

This is ignoring some problems like the code changing later and it turns out the items are used later and unexpected null wreck havoc.

Comment: It would make the object available for collection, if it would be significant for your app performance-wise (tons of items or any other reason) go ahead.

Comment: Whether it's a good idea or not is really an opinion, you can decide that one for yourself (you seem aware of the pros and cons). As far as making it available for GC, if nothing is referencing an object it should be eligible.

Comment: It is obviously bad idea in sense of code will look strange and broken... But since (presumably) you've spend significant amount of time proving that this change will improve performance of your application than couple line of descriptive comments would clear things up.

Comment: If, for performance reasons, you do this, make sure you add a comment to let future maintainers know - it's not a common thing to do

Comment: As others mentioned it would make the object available for GC, but I think you'd be better off using a Stack (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and using Pop. It might end up being more efficient.

Comment: Sounds like something you'd need to profile. If the garbage collection doesn't fire during your loop, then it shouldn't make any difference at all. And *probably* you don't want garbage collection in the middle of your loop anyway.

Comment: Yes it will make the object available for GC if it is the only root but wait a minute. Why you need to set it to null? Why not just remove it?

Comment: If you would want to do this, it is probably for the reason of storing some rather large object inside your `List<T>`. If this is done, you should probably rethink your strategy as of how you store these large values. Else, i wouldn't explictly make an attempt to tell the GC anything, simply let it figure it out for itself (hoping you don't have any reference to your `List<T>` anywhere else).

Comment: @BillDinger: Wouldn't a queue be better? It would be FIFO rather than LIFO and would match the processing order of the original. But depending on what *exactly* "some stuff is done with the list" actually is - neither might work here.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - Removing item from list is O(n) compared to setting item to null (O(1))... And whole iteration will become O(n^2) which is not the best way to improve performance :)

Comment: I'm not removing because removal at the head of a list is O(n). I considered using another data structure like a queue, but that did not seem natural in the context of the other code where as a list does.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Then you're using a wrong data-structure and you need a different one. Setting null is hacky. `Queue` is the best fit it seems.

Comment: Overall, I'd be inclined to not do this unless you profile your code and identify this as an *actual, real problem*. This feels like an attempt at premature optimization and feels hacky.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes... But note that inside of Queue/Stack the code is likely to do exactly the same thing - so while for general code it is bad, there is not much can be done if you *are* implementing `SuperQueueCoolerThanYours` .

Comment: It isn't exactly wrong, but the missing `items.Clear();` is a very major code-smell.

Comment: @MattBurland are there any reason to expect that GC should NOT happen during the loop?  Is this a typical optimization of the Garbage Collector in a general scenario, or is it something to consider on a case by case basis?

Comment: @nlh3 it is typical to expect that GC *will not happen any time soon*, there is no particular relation between loops and GC. There are a lot of articles about when GC will happen and when it is sensible to trigger it yourself - consider searching (something like ".Net GC internals" may be good search terms).

Comment: @nlh3 No, it is not sensible to assume the GC will run during your loop.  The GC doesn't need to be fired off very often.  It will typically run very rarely.  While it's certainly *possible* that it'll run during the loop, it's extremely unlikely.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If the only root-accessible reference to that object is through that list, then yes, setting that reference to `null` will make that object *eligible* for garbage collection.

When a garbage collection eventually happens, if that object ends up being cleaned up while the list itself needs to stay around, then you will have decreased the memory footprint of your application by the size of that object.

Note that the memory allocated for the reference to the object in the list will still be there; it is only the memory for the object that it references that can be cleaned up.

As many others have mentioned, your usage of this data structure strongly indicates that you should not be using a `List` in the first place, but rather a `Queue` or another comparable data structure, as that would fit your usage much more effectively.

You also need to keep in mind that memory is cheap; people tend to have a lot of it.  Unless you have many thousands of objects that would otherwise be kept alive for long periods of time, this is unlikely to be enough of an improvement for you to even notice it; you may not even be capable of measuring the difference.  Using the correct data structure would give you all of those benefits, and more, *and* make the code dramatically simpler, and more readable/maintainable.

Comment: Actually, this is wrong.  Objects become eligible for collection [as soon as the JIT and/or GC can prove you aren't using them any more](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/10/10048149.aspx), even if there's still a live reference.  So, you don't necessarily *need* to set `items[i]` to null, and doing so will not necessarily improve performance.

Comment: @Kevin: Given that the OP *is* still using `items`, I rather doubt that the JIT and/or GC will seek to prove that (s)he is no longer using some of its elements.

Comment: @Kevin The JIT has no idea which elements of the list you actually use or not. The article you reference shows how set-use analysis of stack variables can be used to provide the GC with info but this is not applicable in this case because the entire contents of the list live on the heap.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, if list has last reference to an object setting element to given index to null makes object eligible for GC.

It is not a good idea:

- code will look strange. Possibly good comment *why* it is done can help.
- there are likely better ways to express that behavior.

If you tried setting element to null and profiling shows measurable increase in performance/scalability/whatever you are looking for - consider rewriting code to use some other more appropriate construct that better express temporary nature of the list (maybe Queue, Stack or just IEnumrable with lazy evaluation)

When it may be beneficial (make sure to profile to prove):

- list contains large managed objects like Bitmaps or MemoryStream. In this case GC have good chance to actually automatically run and clean up objects (assuming there are more allocations during iteration)
- list contains small managed objects holding large un-managed objects (like globally allocated memory handles) - setting to null + proper Dispose + force GC may be needed to trigger early cleanup (GC will not detect un-managed memory pressure)
- list is used as backing storage for some data structure like custom Stack, Queue or CircularBuffer as part of your own library - setting element to `default(T)` / `null` is a smart way to prevent your custom data structure to prolong lifetime of objects no longer used by your type.

Note that in case of implementing custom data type you likely must do that due to general contract of data type and not due to profiling - i.e. it is expected that Stack completely forgets about object after "Pop". The code should have appropriate comment next to `internalBuffer[i]=null;` -  i.e. "avoid holding reference after object removed from Stack".

Answer (score 1):

As discussed elsewhere, setting to `null` should allow the object to be garbage collected.

You say in a comment

> I considered using another data structure like a queue, but that did not seem natural in the context of the other code where as a list does.

You could always initialize a `Queue` from a list:

```
List<T> list = GetList<T>();

Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>(list); // O(n)

list.Clear(); // to free up memory as per requirement
```

Answer (score 0):

[CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=16273) can be used to find memory allocated to functions, classes and assemblies to evaluate performance.

***Some references:***

[.NET Best Practice No: 1:- Detecting High Memory consuming functions in .NET code](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shivprasadk/net-best-practice-no-1-detecting-high-memory-consuming-functions-in-net-code/)

[Monitoring the Activities of Garbage Collection in .NET Using CLR Profiler](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/7ca517/monitoring-the-activities-of-garbage-collection-in-net-usin/)